# ¿Como llamar un selection list en surveytogo?

Tags: javascript

Es un formado de ingreso de datos: precio de entrada y precio de salida, cada uno es un select y quiero hacer una condicion si para que valide que el precio de salida sea mayor que el precio de entrada.